# Uncaught Invariant Violation: reactjs, load array

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, reactive-programming

the error should this in what I call the arrangemen

```js
var Modulo5_ = React.createClass({ 
render: function() {
  return(
       <img src={this.props.ruta} className="img-responsive" />
       <p>{this.props.title}</p>
)
}) 

var Modulo5 = React.createClass({ 
    getInitialState: function(){
     return { tituloRopa:[
       {titulo:'ropa uno', ruta:'img/img1.jpg'},
   {titulo:'ropa dos', ruta:'img/img2.jpg'},
   {titulo:'ropa tres', ruta:'img/img3.jpg'},
      ]}
     },
    render: function(){
     return(
      <header>
         <div>
        {
          this.state.tituloRopa.map(function(titleRop, rutaRop,  i){
        return(
          <Modulo5_ key={i} title={tituloRop} ruta={rutaRop}>
                                      </Modulo5_> 
        )
          })
        }
                </div>
       </header>
      )
     }

    })
```

and i have this error:
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {titulo, ruta}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Modulo5_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code there are several mistakes

1. React component must have only one root element

   ```
   var Modulo5_ = React.createClass({ 
     render: function() {
        return <div>
          <img src={this.props.ruta} className="img-responsive" />
          <p>{this.props.title}</p>
        </div>
     }
   })
   ```
2. In [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) first argument is element being processed in the array, so in this case it is `Object` therefore you need just get properties from it using `.` notation(`el.titulo`)

   ```
   {this.state.tituloRopa.map(function(el,  i) {
      return <Modulo5_ key={i} title={el.titulo} ruta={el.ruta } />
   })}
   ```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/34400/)

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous function in the map uses incorrect parameters. Array.prototype.map gives calls your mapper function with each item in the array as the first parameter and the index as the second parameter. Try the following.

```js
   this.state.tituloRopa.map(function(item,  i){
 return(
   <Modulo5_ key={i} title={item.tituloRop} ruta={item.rutaRop}></Modulo5_> 
 )
   })
```